# File separator customized

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to change file separators used in the build system variables from Sublime Text? I want change variables like $file from C:\Files\Chapter1.txt to C:/Files/Chapter1.txt, for example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I think you could do is modify `Default/exec.py` and replace `\` with `/`. You could also try writing your own plugin to do substitutions the way you want, then call the proper command. Doing this though would require a lot more work, as you would also have to integrate it with ST in general. Other than those two options, I don't think it is possible to replace the file separators on the fly. Out of curiosity, why do you want to change what separators are used?

Comment: Thanks. I will try. I'm doing a JavaC.sublime-build to work with differents project configurations and without external tools.

Comment: I see, though I still don't really understand why you would need to modify the default separator. You may also want to take a look at maven or ant if you haven't already. I've found that to be easier to work with in terms of building Java projects.

Comment: The default separator dont works with the way that files are manipulated in the JavaC.sublime-build. Now I see that is more easy use ant, maven or even gradle. May be that using regex is possible. I will try when have time. To another people that will try this, the answer was possible but with some side effects.